# angularjs undefined resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I am new in angularJs, I am trying to have my first steps in developping an application and I am facing a problem.

I am calling an external resource that return an object json via $resource.get(), in the callBack I am getting the correct values, but in the service the values are undefined, the problem is when I am printing the resource in the console the result has the correct values.

my json object :

```
{
"readOnly": false,
"questions": [
{
    "questionId": "0",
    "questionTitle": "question0",
    "isMondatory": true,
    "responseList": [
        {
        "questionId": "0",
        "questionTitle": null,
        "responseId": "00",
        "responseTitle": "response00"
        },
        {
        "questionId": "0",
        "questionTitle": null,
        "responseId": "01",
        "responseTitle": "response01"
        },
        {
        "questionId": "0",
        "questionTitle": null,
        "responseId": "02",
        "responseTitle": "response02"
        },
        {
        "questionId": "0",
        "questionTitle": null,
        "responseId": "03",
        "responseTitle": "response03"
        }
        ]
    },
    {
    "questionId": "1",
    "questionTitle": "question1",
    "isMondatory": true,
    "responseList": [
        {
        "questionId": "1",
        "questionTitle": null,
        "responseId": "10",
        "responseTitle": "response10"
        },
        {
        "questionId": "1",
        "questionTitle": null,
        "responseId": "11",
        "responseTitle": "response11"
        },
        {
        "questionId": "1",
        "questionTitle": null,
        "responseId": "12",
        "responseTitle": "response12"
        },
        {
        "questionId": "1",
        "questionTitle": null,
        "responseId": "13",
        "responseTitle": "response13"
        }
        ]
    }
```

my controller is

```
app.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope,myservice) {
 $scope.infos = null;
 $scope.infos = myservice.getInfo();  
}
```

my service is :

```
angular.module('xxxx').factory('myservice', function($window,$resource,$routeParams,$http,apicallservice) {

// Public API here
return {

    getInfo : function(){
        var result=null;
        var url = "myUrl";
        result = apicallservice.GetApiCall(url,$routeParams);
        console.log(result.readOnly); // print undefined => KO
        return result;
},
//.... other functions
```

my apicallservice :

```
angular.module('xxxx')
  .factory('apicallservice', function ($http,$resource) {

  var result;

// Public API here
return {

  GetApiCall: function (url,obj) {

      // resource         
      var resource = $resource(url,{param1:obj});

      // cal the api              
      result = resource.get(function(callBack) {
          console.log(callBack.readOnly); => print false => OK
          return callBack;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);         
        return error;
    });


    return result;
  },

  PostApiCall : function(url,obj){
      result = $http.post(url,obj).then(
              function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                  }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
  }
};
```

});

please can you help me ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was going wrong, in the controller I had to add then() :
instead of this :

```
 app.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope,myservice) {
  $scope.infos = null;
  $scope.infos = myservice.getInfo();  
 }
```

do this :

```
app.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope,myservice) {
 $scope.infos = null;
  myservice.getInfo().then(function(data) {  
           $scope.infos = data;
        });  
}
```

this resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From angularjs api [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) for $resource

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick
>   since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then
>   rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering,
>   once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated
>   with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the
>   new data. This means that in most cases one never has to write a
>   callback function for the action methods.

So basically for
`$scope.infos = myservice.getInfo();`,
`result` will have an `empty` `object/array` reference. Since the call is asynchronous, the next line(`console.log(result.readOnly)`) gets called immediately and you will get `undefined`. Only when the underlying `get/post` call actually completes, variable `result` will be populated with the value from the server

Comment: So do you have some suggestions for my problem ?

Comment: So you want the `console.log(..)` display the correct values immediately after you call `apicallservice.GetApiCall(..)`? Thats impossible due to asynchronous nature of the $resource methods. What you can do is return the `resource` object back (or $http.get or $http.post promises) and initialize the value(and print in the console) in the callback function. But that defeats the whole purpose of using $resource

Comment: the console.log() is not my problem, my problem is that in my view I can't display the results

Comment: How are you using it in the view? Technically, the view should be rendered automatically with the correct data once its actually loaded from the get/post calls

Comment: I am simply displaying the data like this :     '<div>
  <form>
   <table class="table">
    <tbody>
    {{quiz.readOnly}} 
    <tr ng-repeat="q in quiz.questions" >
       <td>{{q.questionTitle}}</td> 
    </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </form>
 </div>'

Comment: How is quiz defined in scope?